# Trying to understand rövarspråket translator

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, for-loop

I'm doing a beginner exercise, create a rövarspråket translator.

> Write a function translate() that will translate a text into
>   “rövarspråket”. That is, double every consonant and place an
>   occurrence of "o" in between. For example, translate("this is fun")
>   should return the string "tothohisos isos fofunon".

The solutions I was coming up with were bad, so I found one [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49375/various-simple-javascript-solutions) and am trying to understand it.

```
var translate = function(text) {
  var string = text.toLowerCase();
  var vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", " "];
  var y = "";
  for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     var current = string.charAt(i); 
    if (vowels.indexOf(current) != -1) {
        y = (y + (current));
    } else {
        y = (y + (current + "o" + current));
    }
  }
  return y;
}

console.log(translate("this is fun"));
```

- Why does `if (vowels.indexOf(current) != -1)` need `-1` specifically? I tried `-2`, `-1000`, `1000`, but they all break the function.
- If I change `y = "";` to `y = "XYZ"`, `translate("this is fun")` returns "XYZtothohisos isos fofunon". Why is it only before the first consonant and not all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does `if (vowels.indexOf(current) != -1)` need -1 specifically? I tried -2, -1000, 1000, but they all break the function.

Well, that's just what [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns when the character is not found. If you compare to anything else, it would assume to always see a vowel, and never translate anything.

> If I change `y = "";` to `y = "XYZ"`, `translate("this is fun")` returns `"XYZtothohisos isos fofunon"`. Why is it only before the first consonant and not all of them?

Because it has nothing to do with consonants. `y` is the accumulator, buffer, whatever you may call it, to which the translated results are appended item by item. It naturally starts (is initialised with) the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns exactly `-1` when it cannot find `current` in `vowels`. This is an old convention from other languages where return values all need to be the same type (in this case integers). If Javascript was invented today it would possibly return `null` or `false` instead.
- `y` is, *in this function only*, the return value of the function. It starts out empty and each iteration of the `for` loop will add more text to `y`. If you set `y="XYZ"` it will add text after `XYZ`. The function is meant to start out with an empty `y`.